# servlet chain filter

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

How can I write a filter class to pass the response from one servlet to another along with the GET parameters?

This is the outline of what I've tried (I got most of it from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974101/legacy-servlet-chaining-using-servlet-aliasing))

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class TranslateFilter implements Filter {

  private FilterConfig config = null;

  public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    this.config = config;
  }

  public void destroy() {
    config = null;
  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    ..

    RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Translate");
    dispatch.forward(request, response); 
    ..
  }
}
```

and this in the web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>process</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Process
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>translate</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Translate
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>processChain</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>process</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

But it doesn't not work. It's not forwarding to the second servlet. I don't have a debugging environment setup so I can't tell where it's failing but can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `chain.doFilter(request, response);`is this conditional ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi are you asking if it returns a boolean?

Comment: Why wouldn't you post this as part of your original question? You've omitted some important details of the answer I provided, namely that you should pass a response wrapper that acts as a buffer instead of the original response object.

Comment: @kschneid Previously I didn't realize using a filter would solve my issue; my first question was very generic. I was trying to implement the filter but I'm not quite there yet. In this post I was trying to get some answers regarding implementing filters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `FilterChain#doFilter()` continues the request processing and only returns when the target controllers have finished their job and the response is been rendered and committed.

You should **not** invoke it if your intent is to change the request to a different server side destination by `RequestDispatcher#forward()` (or when you want to let the client side send a new request by `HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`). You should have noticed this by seeing `IllegalStateException: response already committed` in the server logs.

So, either remove it so that you only end up with the forward,

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/Translate").forward(request, response);
```

or make it a conditional

```
if (someCondition) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/Translate").forward(request, response); 
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, if I understand/guess your actual functional requirement right, you're more looking for the `RequestDispatcher#include()` in the `/process` servlet. See also [How do I execute multiple servlets in sequence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024949/how-do-i-execute-a-sequence-of-servlets)

Comment: If you look at the original question, and my comment on this question, you'll notice that some important details have been omitted...